# AKS mixed GPU and CPU cluster management

Tags: azure, tensorflow, azure-aks

I want to have AKS cluster with a few GPU and much more CPU instances, so the ETL jobs are executed on CPU but training is on GPU instances, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the AKS supports GPU. Actually, the GPU just means a serial VM sizes. So you can create the AKS cluster with the GPU sizes and then there will be GPU for your cluster nodes. For more details, see [Use GPUs for compute-intensive workloads on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/gpu-cluster).

There is a limitation that the AKS cluster nodes will be the same size and cannot change after you create the cluster. You should pay attention to this point. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment, as AKS supports a single pool for now. Multiple pool support is on the way, that will allow you to create pools with different sizes/capabilities.